# Show p-value in seaborn.jointplot

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn

I'm having a hard time finding out how to show "p" and "pearsonr" values in seaborn plots (as well as just get them), as it seems latest versions no longer show them as default.

Code i'm using:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.jointplot('A','A',tech_rets,kind='reg',color='seagreen')
```

As you can predict, p and pearsonr values are expected to be 0 and 1, respectively.

I've been through several posts here in stackoverflow, which answers sugest using a jointgrid method, such as:

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy as stats

sns.jointplot('A','A',tech_rets,kind='reg',color='seagreen').annotate(stats.pearsonr)
```

But then, it seems that "stats.pearsonr" is outdated.

Thank you in advance!